# pandas select 'object' data type using select_dtypes()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, kaggle

I tried to select 'object' data columns only w/o the numeric data,
on this data set
https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

the float data were selected also
[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xm5N.png)

Comment: Please verify that the column is `float` type with `train_set.info()`

Comment: @dm2 I did that already.

Answer (score 0):

Filter using numpy :

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.object]
```

or simply try below:

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == object]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: try: df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.dtype('O')]

Comment: @woblob Unfortunately, nothing changed also.